# Can't get method/attribute completion hint in PhpStorm, with global object

Tags: php, phpstorm

I expected this to work and it is not...am I doing something wrong that is preventing PhpStorm from providing auto-complete class member hints for the global object `$G_myobject`?  Version of IDE is 2016.3.2

**file1.php**

```
namespace sysbase;

$a = true;
if ( $a ) {
    $G_myobject = new SomeClass();
}
```

**file2.php**

```
namespace sysbase;
require_once file1.php

$b = true;
global $G_myobject;     //without this line, the IDE complains 'unknown variable'
if ( $b ) {
    $G_myobject-> ....  //not getting any class member hints here, in the IDE...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because phpStorm cannot process **if** statement your object in **if**,  will be only seen inside the  if scope by phpStorm. So you should init your object out of **if** clause. Please try the code below for your file1.php it should work

```
$G_myobject = new SomeClass();

$a = true;
if ( $a ) {
    $G_myobject = new SomeClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because PHPStorm has no idea what object/data type `$G_myobject` is (within the context of file2.php) it doesn't know what hints to provide.

You can either do as 'Ali insan Soyaslan' suggests, or you have to type hint your variable using the `/** @var Classname $variableName */` comment notation so that PHPStorm knows what it is. In your case it would be as follows:

```
namespace sysbase;
require_once file1.php

$b = true;

/** @var SomeClass $G_myobject */
global $G_myobject;

if ($b) {
    $G_myobject-> ....  //should now get hints
}
```